# java - update .json file (using json.simple)

Tags: java, json

I have a .json file that i am using like a property file.  After reading the json file, i get the value from "Execute" node and then I want to update the "Execute" node with a value of "N".

My json file looks like this. {"RunDate":"2015-01-12","Execute":"Y"}.  I wrote the code to read the json file and i am trying to update the file by writing a new file.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("c:\\B\\myControl.json");

        Object obj = parser.parse(fr);

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        ExecuteRun = (String) jsonObject.get("Execute");

        RunDate = (String) jsonObject.get("RunDate");
        //update

        jsonObject.put("Execute", "N");
        jsonObject.put("RunDate", RunDate);

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("c:\\B\\mycontrol.json", true);
        try {
            file.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The FileWriter line gets "access denied" error.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is there more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Looks like you still have the file open (for reading) in the first line.

Comment: Close the FileReader. Depending on a lot of things, often you can't write to a file while something else is reading from it.

Comment: Yes, closing the FileReader did it!!  Thanks Stuart Siegler and immibis!

Answer (score 0):

```
//this worked for me

    package com.FLP.utils;

    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Reader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;

   import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
   import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
   import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
   import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public class TestDataReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

    try (Reader reader = new FileReader(".\\testdata\\TC_11.json")) {
        // Read JSON file
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
        data.put(key value);
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(".\\testdata\\TC_11.json");
        file.write(data.toJSONString());
        file.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   }
```

Answer (score -1):

place this code

```
try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/C:/Users/itaas/Desktop/text1.txt")) {
            file.write(js.toString());
            System.out.println("Successfully Copied JSON Object to File...");
            System.out.println("\nJSON Object: " + js);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```